# Does the iphone sdk support playing an mp4 from rtmp stream?

Tags: iphone, rtmp

Does the iphone sdk support playing mp4 files from RTMP streams?  I am looking to store the files in CloudFront (in a bucket marked to stream) and would like to have an iphone app be able to play them.  Is this possible, or am I better off storing the files as mp3 on CloudFront and not enabling streaming via RTMP?

Comment: you can use uiwebview or Vitamio player

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. The iOS SDK does not support the RTSP protocol.  You may be allowed to include an implementation of RTSP into your app, but Apple is strongly pushing their HTTP streaming technique.  Also: beware of this rule from section 9.4 of the [developer guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> Video streaming content over a
>   cellular network longer than 10
>   minutes must use HTTP Live Streaming
>   and include a baseline 64 kbps
>   audio-only HTTP Live stream

I believe everyone is using Apple's [HTTP Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) technology.  It is the supported and blessed approach.

Comment: Than q sooooo much for u r answer

Comment: Just for reference, it has since been updated and moved to another section: 2.5.7 Video streaming content over a cellular network longer than 10 minutes must use HTTP Live Streaming and include a baseline 192 kbps HTTP Live stream.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the [Wunder Radio](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wunder-radio/id292233889?mt=8) application from iTunes. It is open source under LGPL license. The code is available from here - http://www.wunderradio.com/code.html

Comment: Looks like wunderground used ffmpeg, which has integrated support.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research into a video app I did on iPod last month, iOS does not support streaming ANYTHING using RTMP. If I am mistaken, I would be thrilled to hear that.