# RTMP (Real Time Media Player) format in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, rtmp

Is iPhone supports RTMP (Real Time Media Player) Video format to play into iphone/ipod or ipad?

On website, it is working with flash player, like JWPlayer, but i doubt whether its supported with iPhone as we will be generating APIs parsing XML.

Any ideas, would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: its wonder, as no one tried anything like this ever?

Comment: Wunderground has implemented this within wunderradio using ffmpeg.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3828090/843000

Comment: @mbrownnyc: thanks for information, sure will have a look at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No...

There is no RTMP streaming to IOS devices.  Apple is keen on [HTTP Live Streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming), which is closely related to [MPEG-TS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream).

Comment: thanks for your response, I was waiting since long for this :)